# How to get the timer running application

Tags: java, android

I need to get the timer in Application manager. I have 2 application and I need to get the time, both in the list of running applications in Settings. 
[image]

As you can see, there is a timer indicates when service is running. But I need to get a timer and no service applications. How do I get it?
I do not even have a presentation where you want to dig, how to get them?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a timer use handler...If u want it to run even in background implement in service...you can get the value from timer whenever needed...If you want to know further, provide me with additional details...